# Can't seem to find what this date format is

Tags: date, calendar

I'm trying to interface with a program at work and I have to provide data based on dates.

However the weeks don't seem to be standard, this is not ISO, this is not calendar, what is it?

[image]

the only thing I can think of right now is to go from 2018 and add 7 days again and again until I reach the date I need. Then compute which years have 52 or 53 weeks and do some math to get to the week that I'm interested in.

Comment: These weeks seem to go from Saturday to Friday. It seems week 1 begins on the Saturday in the range 29th December through 4th January (since this is 7 days, there will always be exactly one). Thus the definition of week 1 is akin to ISO: Week one is the first week that has at least 4 days in the new year. I cannot recall having met this system before either. My immediate guess is it’s something homegrown. You may also search for calendar systems that have Saturday as first day of week, though, you never know.

Comment: According to [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000229511&type=1) Saturday is the first day of the week in many places. [This one](http://chartsbin.com/view/41671) also mentions more than 10  examples.

Comment: I just decompiler the jar of the program generating the weeks, it's from a class named "Kalender", they made their own week implementation.

The weeks are generated following 2 rules : `goes from staturday to friday` - `if the week has 4 or more days being part of a specific year then it's a week of the said year`

Answer (score 0):

> - [the week] goes from staturday to friday
> - if the week has 4 or more days being part of a specific year then it's a week of the said year

The `WeekFields` class of my Java 9 knows a lot of locales that have Saturday as first day of week, but they all require just 1 day in week 1 of the year. Your observations and mine both seem to indicate that this could be a homegrown system.

If you are using Java, `WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, 4)` will give you the definition of weeks used by the program you are interfacing with.